# Managing server failover in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, failover

I am creating a simple application where clients invoke services on a server through WCF.I also want to create a backup server which when the main server fails,can nominate one of the clients as the new primary server.What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: You mean that if your server goes down, my PC (your client) will become the server?

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! The question is quite vague and/or very broad. Please consider adding more details, tell us what you've tried or considered so far and what your specific issues with those solutions was.

Comment: Nominate client to become a server?

Comment: Hide your servers behind a load balancer. If availability is a problem, use a message queuing system like NServiceBus.

Comment: explaining my problem a little more below ..There is only one node initially(say N1), whose address all connecting nodes know about.After a few nodes have connected to N1,N1 then nominates one of the connected nodes as its backup and they keep syncing their global data.Now if N1 were to go down,then the backup should take over as the primary and then nominate one of the connected nodes to be the backup.Hope I am making sense here.Can you suggest if this is even possible using WCF?

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple load balancer solve your problem? This business of turning clients into servers is ... unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I think John may have mistakenly written client.
John, what I understood is "you wanted to have a backup server which can act as primary server in case of failover". right?

I think WCF Routing can be a solution to this. Please follow the discussion on MSDN for your answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c1f148f4-b27f-466a-ba99-4e413b68b455

Comment: No,it means what it says.Let me explain it a little better. There is only one node initially(say N1), whose address all connecting nodes know about.After a few nodes have connected to N1,N1 then nominates one of the connected nodes as its backup and they keep syncing their global data.Now if N1 were to go down,then the backup should take over as the primary and then nominate one of the connected nodes to be the backup.Hope I am making sense here.Can you suggest if this is even possible using WCF?